# Connectivity between VM's in the same VNET

Tags: networking, azure

I have a couple of virtual machines in one Cloud Service. They are assigned to the same VNET and have received private IP addresses in the same subnet.

I noticed that I was unable to PING from one server to another and when I started to look into it there is no connectivity whatsoever between the servers. I have disabled windows firewall on both servers but that didn't do the trick.

Just now I tried on one of the vm's to ping the internal ip address assigned to itself but it fails.

Can anyone shed some light into this? Is this expected behavior?

The reason I am looking into this right now is because we are adding a third VM to do some performance monitoring and since the other two VM's are part of a Cloud Service we cannot open endpoints to both of them using the same port and need to go directly to the internal IP's.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue not too long ago. I had three servers in the same vnet that were able to communicate via site-to-site VPN to my HQ but could not communicate with one another. After several hours of banging my head against the desk, I ended up just re-building the vnet and connectivity to one another was restored successfully. The vnet router feature had become corrupt and could no longer send traffic internally.

To rebuild the vnet, you'll need to delete the VM's. Keep the disks though, and you can re-build them quickly after the new vnet is back online.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I might end up down that road but since the servers are hosting an application that are in use that option is not very appeasing at the moment. I hope there is a better solution out there since this workaround might work but there is no guarantee that the same issue will not come back. Did you register a case with MS for your issue?